# Job work rotation plan, how to automate it with google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, rotation, jobs

I'm using google sheets to make a job rotation. There are 32 workers. I want to give each employee a ID, so if one chooses to quit the new employer gets the same ID as the one who left.
Question: Can I automate this process? Meaning can I have a separate spreadsheet With names that automatically fills in on an ID in another spreadsheet?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk9GT.jpg)

Comment: The short answer is yes. Beyond that, as you don't have anything set up or any actual data for us to look at, there isn't much anyone can tell you about it, I'm afraid.

Comment: I`m straight out very new to this. Kind of hoping for a quick fix. I will go an do my homework :-)  This is my spreadsheet. ID is rotating, meaning person "a" with ID 1 is first on monday, next rotation on fridag, than thurstday and so on. If I could only have a updatet column B in another spresdshet that autofilled into their ID it would be very easy. Perhaps not that claryfing, bur maybe?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y4p1ld3lJgYRjgE31BT8Z3FM2GSr4dFv3O0j2YO85yc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sharing the spreadsheet is a good start. However, in looking at that spreadsheet, the goal is still entirely unclear to me. Your post says you have 32 workers, but your sheet shows only 30. You have dates listed chronologically, Monday through Friday, with no holidays (which might be what really happens in your situation, but which seems unlikely). And it appears you have one person "on" per day. It's hard to imagine the context for this. In addition, it's just not clear from the sheet what *you* plan to enter, what you want a formula to do, and what you want the formula output to look like.

Comment: Ok. Im a union representativ for a countryside emergency rom. Im trying to see how we can make a fair system for rotation between docs. The woman ho does this is using alot of time making the plan, with big turnovers and changes of docs. If she has a fixed excel, with colum A rotating the "ID" and than another sheet that connect names with ID than the program will fix it for her. Than she could only change the name  of the id with the new doctor ho replace him/her. I dont know if this was any clearer, obviously this is not my best skills ;-)

Comment: Hilde, this project is probably bigger than this forum is going to be able to accommodate. You said you were hoping for a "quick fix," and there really isn't one. This would require the building of a *system* requiring more exploration as to the specifics of how things work at the medical facility, the development of several sheets, construction of complex formulas, etc. You'd also need many controls built in. For instance, if formulas assign Person A to a certain Monday and they have to call out, you'd need a way to fill in that shift without disrupting the formula.

Comment: Stack, being a fully volunteer-run free forum, is really here to share knowledge or to help people tweak formulas or scripts they've already written themselves and nearly gotten right. It isn't a place where complex, time-intensive solutions can be built from the ground up at no cost. I realize that you didn't come asking for that. As you said, you were hoping there was some sort of "quick fix." But again, unfortunately, there just isn't. Someone might write "a formula" for you, but it won't likely address the full situation as I see it.